# How many such triangles exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $ABC$ be a arbitrary triangle with integral sides such that the perimeter is $2006$. And one of the side $16$ times the other side. How many such triangles exist?

**Attempt**

[image]

Comment: Note that the length of the longest side of a triangle must be less than the sum of the lengths of the two shorter sides. This gives the additional requirements $15 x < y < 17 x$.

Comment: Note that $2006=(118)(17)$, So all integer solutions of $17x+y=2006$ have shape $y=17t$, $x=118-t$. Now we need to pick out the $t$ that give us a real triangle.

Comment: Be careful, a straight line is not a triangle :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer some hints.

You've got the basic relationship:

$$17x + y = 2006,$$

where $x$ is the shortest side and $y$ is the side not constrained to be $16$ times the shortest side, $16x$.

Now consider this.  What other relation constrains the sides?  Hint:  $(1, 16, 1989)$ aren't valid sides for a triangle, even though they add up to $2006$ and have one side sixteen times another.  Why not?

This should make the number of triples manageable.